# syncing a file to the web, and accessing through a "custom" url

Tags: custom-url, public-folders

Are there any websites out there that allows file **syncing** to a folder and the files in the folder can be accessed through the folder via http?
  i.e.  My folder to be synced could be called "share." And a file can be "file.txt".
   I want to access it through...*http://whicheverDomain.com/IDontCareWhatThisIs/share/file.txt*

Also I want the file itself to be able to be accessed directly, so that I can send it to google doc viewer. i.e (http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2FwhicheverDomain.com%2FIDontCareWhatThisIs%2Fshare%2Ffile.txt).  If that doesn't work, then if the website displays it in a decent manner, that would be fine.

I've been looking for a while. Box seems to be able to do that, but it requires a business account.

Comment: Have you looked at Dropbox? You can get links to files in the folders (ie access them via http) or links to the folders or just browse your own collection of folders from the dropbox website.

Comment: I did look at Dropbox. However,  it is not what I want.  I want to put a file in a folder "share" and know automatically I can access the file as "http://.../share/file". Dropbox

Comment: This is an example of what Dropbox did for me.               https://www.dropbox.com/sh/twni9369dsrndc6/mn1v0aYpIX - is the url to "share". https://www.dropbox.com/s/pm75xfsa69osae4/firstFile.txt is the url to "share/fistFile.txt" and https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pnyfaoubktaozx/secondFile.txt is the url to "share/secondFile.txt."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Dropbox doesn't have a "custom url." However, it does have what I was looking for.  Adding their old Public folder does the trick.  You can get it here towards the bottom of the page. https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en